# How to display live yahoo finance stock data in android .... the json format is given below

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, ajax

```
 finance_charts_json_callback( { "meta" :
 {
  "uri" :"/instrument/1.0/PTC/chartdata;type=quote;range=1d/json/",
  "ticker" : "ptc",
  "Company-Name" : "PTC Inc.",
  "Exchange-Name" : "NMS",
  "unit" : "MIN",
  "timezone" : "EDT",
  "currency" : "USD",
  "gmtoffset" : -14400,
  "previous_close" : 32.2800
 }
 ,
 "Timestamp" : {"min" :1458653400,"max" :1458676800 }
 ,
 "labels" : [1458655200,1458658800,1458662400,1458666000,1458669600,1458673200,1458676800 ]
 ,
 "ranges" : {"close" : {"min" :32.1500,"max" :32.6750 },"high" : {"min" :32.1500,"max" :32.6750 },"low" : {"min" :32.1500,"max" :32.6616 },"open" : {"min" :32.1500,"max" :32.6616 },"volume" : {"min" :0,"max" :57300 } }
 ,
 "series" : [
 { "Timestamp" :1458653513,"close" :32.3800,"high" :32.3800,"low" :32.3700,"open" :32.3700,"volume" :3900 } 
, { "Timestamp" :1458653582,"close" :32.5000,"high" :32.5450,"low" :32.5000,"open" :32.5450,"volume" :1800 } 
, { "Timestamp" :1458653656,"close" :32.4900,"high" :32.5300,"low" :32.4900,"open" :32.5300,"volume" :900 } 
, { "Timestamp" :1458653721,"close" :32.5000,"high" :32.5100,"low" :32.4700,"open" :32.4800,"volume" :1000 } 
, { "Timestamp" :1458653761,"close" :32.4650,"high" :32.5100,"low" :32.4500,"open" :32.4500,"volume" :800 } 
, { "Timestamp" :1458653836,"close" :32.4200,"high" :32.4600,"low" :32.4200,"open" :32.4500,"volume" :1300 `enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make a http request to retrieve the data. Check this guide for help: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html
Then you need to serialize the Json data using something like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson). Next you should create a new layout for the data to be displayed in. After that create a new adapter to handle the data. You can check out this guide on help: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: How can it display on timeseries live graphh

Comment: Not sure about getting it 'live'. But you could make a request every minute or so. To display it on a graph, you could use any of these libraries: https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui/blob/master/pages/Graph.md